# Globbing with gulp not working as expected

Tags: gulp, glob, gulp-watch

This gulp.watch copies the file `../server confs/oc.fr/http.conf` to the directory `server_etc_httpd_conf/` when changed/saved:

```
 gulp
  .watch(['../server confs/oc.fr/httpd.conf'])
  .on('change', function(path) {
    gulp
      .src(path)
      .on('end', function(){ log('pass 1: '+path); })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('server_etc_httpd_conf/'))
      .on('end', function(){ log('pass 2: '+path); });
  });
```

**Output:**

```
[09:39:05] Starting 'watch'...
[09:39:12] pass 1: ../server confs/oc.fr/httpd.conf
[09:39:12] pass 2: ../server confs/oc.fr/httpd.conf
```

But when I change the watch list to use a wild card:
`.watch(['../server confs/oc.fr/.'])`
the output messages are identical, but the file does not actually get copied. I tried: `*.conf` `*` `*.*` `.` - they all enter the function correctly as the pass messages show, but no file is being copied. What's wrong?

**EDIT:** Now I discovered, that, if using the wild card `.`, gulp.dest will create a new, relative target directory `server confs/oc.fr/` and store the output file there. I still don't understand this behavior. The output path 'server_etc_httpd_conf/' is explicitly given to gulp.dest.

Answer (score 0):

Add the base property to gulp.src, if using relative source paths containing `..`

```
.src(path, {"base": "../server confs/oc.fr/"})
```